# How do I get webpack-dev-server to accept POST requests

Tags: post, webpack, webpack-dev-server

In my project I call:

```
$ webpack-dev-server --history-api-fallback
```

And it starts an express server (I'm assuming) available on `localhost:8080`.

It works great except that I want to submit a form via POST into an iframe loading my app; `localhost:8080` in development and something else in production.

I don't expect to do anything with that POST data in development, but in production, it needs to be POST.

When I try to use POST however, it `cannot find POST /`

Is there a configuration option or some other solution that will allow me to use the `webpack-dev-server`? (I really don't want to have to write my own server for this).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@cowCrazy had half of the story, but didn't show how to respond with the same response for GET in the case of POST, which is what I was looking for.

In the Webpack config, you do this:

```
module.exports = {
    ...,
    devServer: {
        setup(app) {
            app.post('*', (req, res) => {
                res.redirect(req.originalUrl);
            });
        },
    }
}
```

This will just take the POST URL and redirect with the same URL, making it a GET request.

Instead of having a server error, it will redirect with GET.

Comment: according to the documentation `setup` is deprecated in favor of `before`: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserversetup

Answer (score 9):

What you are looking for is [`devServer`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/). Bellow you can see my config for it. Under `setup(app)` you can add "almost" whatever you want:

```js
module.exports = {
    ...,
    devServer: {
        inline: true,

        port: 3000,

        publicPath: '/',

        setup(app){

            var bodyParser = require('body-parser');    
            app.use(bodyParser.json());

            app.get("/get/some-data", function(req, res){
                console.log(req);
                res.send("GET res sent from webpack dev server")
            })

            app.post("/post/some-data", bodyParser.json(), function(req, res){
                console.log(req.body);
                res.send("POST res sent from webpack dev server")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I have pushed a minimalistic [example](https://github.com/cowCrazy/webpack-dev-server-extended) to github if you wanna take a better look.

Comment: What's in `webpack.devServer.setup.js`? I'm no expert at express or `webpack-dev-server`'s use of it.

Comment: There you can build a complete express server which you can use to have `app.post` and other api functionalities. In my project I made it almost a copy of the prod server.js only without access to the `express` var.

Comment: Can you give me some example code? My backend is not an express app and I don't know how I'm supposed to respond to requests.

Comment: @KevinBeal I've edited the code and also attached a github repo. Hope it helps.

Comment: Per the webpack documentation - "This option is deprecated in favor of before and will be removed in v3.0.0." https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx

Answer (score 0):

Check if it solves your problem by converting the POST request to GET request:

```
bypass: function (req, res, proxyOptions) {

      const url = req.url;
      req.method = 'GET';
      if (url.indexOf('?') > -1) {

        return url.replace('?', '.json?');
      } else {

        return url + '.json';
      }
    }
```